# How to make sections in the Script Editor menu

Tags: applescript, menu-bar

I'm aware that I could just put a folder in the Script Editor menu and thus make sub-menus. However, I find that just a tad annoying.

If I put a script in `Scripts/Applications/X`, I'm able to get a new section on the menu that only appears when I'm in application `X`. Is there a way to make a similar section with a custom title that will show on all applications?

Comment: User scripts, that are to be globally available to the User in any/all applications go in `~/Library/Scripts` Scripts for a given User that are to be available only when a given application has focus are to be placed in `~/Library/Scripts/Applications/AppName` where `AppName` is e.g. Finder or any other valid application for this usage. This is how it works and if you really find it annoying I'd suggest you [send feedback to Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/).

Comment: @user3439894 That's not my problem. What I'd like is something *similar* to that that divides the menu into sections, similar to how there's a separate section for each individual application.

Comment: What you want, you can have as it not setup to do it other then the way it is, and you should send feedback to Apple otherwise.

Comment: @user3439894 ??

Comment: This is  bit crappy, but what if you just make an empty script with filename that is just a line. You'd have to use a prefix letter to position it, but otherwise it could just be a line formed by dash. [Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1CG1.png). Another thing to consider might be a third party app called [FastScripts](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/). [Here](https://red-sweater.com/RedSweater/FSFeatures.html) under `Custom Menu Organization` you'll find instructions on how to make a divider in it.